# Represent a matrix in Android - 2*2

Tags: java, matrix

How can I represent a 2*2 Matrix in android. I have a MATLAB code and I want it in Android (not call matlab directly in android). How can I achieve this?

e.g.:

My matrix:
a = [1 dt; 2 1]; % transition matrix

Thanks

Comment: What does this question have to do with Android? This should be tagged Java, not Android. Android is an operating system. Java is a programming language.

Comment: Have you ever created 2 dimensional matrix in java? If so then you can do it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you program your Android app in Java, you'd use a two dimensional array with 2x2 elements. However, I'm not sure what this has to do with Android.